# My spring application isn't recognizing my webservice

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, web-services

My application is returning "[{},{}]" when I request asList. But when I request String it displays ok on browser.

Images: 1.[IDE EndPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSfwd.jpg)  2.[Browser Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLMC0.jpg)

Endpoint

```
package br.com.devdojo.app.endpoint;

import br.com.devdojo.app.model.Student;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("student")
public class StudentEndPoint {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = ("/list"))
    public List<Student> listAll(){
        return asList(new Student("Aluno1"), new Student("Aluno2"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your Student object?

Comment: What output are you expecting? What do you mean by "when I request String"?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Student` class must be like below:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```